# OUTDATED - Sorting 16 and 32 bits instructions of STM in Python

Tags: python, binary, stm32

See [Sorting 16 and 32 bits instructions of STM in Python using endianness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75049781/sorting-16-and-32-bits-instructions-of-stm-in-python-using-endianness) for the updated post

I am using Python to read a hex file containing a STM32 code, that is then converted to big endian, translated to binary, and then re-written in a file with only one instruction per line.

That last part is the problem, because my code is not working properly : some 32-bits instructions are interpreted as a 16-bits instruction, causing the code to not properly divide the instructions.

Here is the function that is used for that separation :

```
def generate_instructions_file():
    instruction_file = open("./instructions_file.txt", "w")
    with open("./binary_reformatted.txt") as file:
        data = file.read()
        i = 0
        while i < len(data)-15:
            tmp = data[i:i+32]
            if tmp[24:27] == '111' and (tmp[27:29] != '00' or tmp[27:29] == '01' or tmp[27:29] == '10' or tmp[27:29] == '11'):
                b0 = tmp[:8]
                b1 = tmp[8:16]
                b2 = tmp[16:24]
                b3 = tmp[24:]
                newtmp = b3 + b2 + b1 + b0
                instruction_file.write(newtmp + '\n')
                i += 32
            else:
                tmp = data[i:i+16]
                b0 = tmp[:8]
                b1 = tmp[8:]
                newtmp = b1 + b0
                instruction_file.write(newtmp + '\n')
                i += 16
```

(The data is converted to little endian to big endian in the function)

An instruction is 32-bits if it starts with '111' but they must not be followed by '00' (therefore an instruction starting with '11100' is a 16-bits)

As an example, here is a part of the resulting file :

```
11110000000000001101001111111011
11110000000000001111100001000101
1111100000011110
11110000010011110100100000011100
```

Here, the third line is supposed to be a 32-bits instruction, and so the 4th should be 16-bits yet my code didn't recognize it.

I've verified every index, they are correct.

I've tried different hex file (they are directly downloaded from STM32CubeProgrammer), they all have this problem

Do you know any solutions? It's probably a coding error, but I still can't find it.

Comment: Could you edit your question to clearly show a small sample of the input data and what the expected result should be. At the moment the only data you have in your question is "wrong data". Having the input data, the expected output, and the code will make it a  [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which will make it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Answer 3:
OK! You have a pre-processor to convert srec file to Ascii bits. That's a long detour that is difficult to justify but it's done. So, let's continue with Ascii bits and concentrate on the logic of your program.
The line:
*if tmp[24:27] == '111' and (tmp[27:29] != '00' or tmp[27:29] == '01' or tmp[27:29] == '10' or tmp[27:29] == '11'):*
means that you check for '111' in characters 24 to 27.
And then you check for 4 possibilities in characters 27 to 29. But there are only 4 possibilities with 2 bits. That means that one of the four will always be True and you will always execute the 32 bit portion of your code.
But your output example show a 16 bits instruction. I deduct that the output example was not generated by the code you show. Confusion, confusion ...
You do not show the code of your pre-processor but I suspect you invert the order of all bits because I don't understand why you use index 27 to test the most significant bit. You need to explain.

Assuming bits are in natural order (0 being the MSB), I would write:

```
tmp = data[i:i+32]
if tmp[0:5] == '11100': # 16 bits instruction start with 11100
  instruction_file.write( tmp[0:16] + '\n')
  i += 16
else: # 32 bits
  instruction_file.write( tmp + '\n')
  i += 32
```

I do not know the STM32.

Comment: Thanks you for your answers. To clarify, an instruction is 32 bits if its start with 111, but must not be followed by 00. Yes, I do invert the bits from in the function because they're written in little endian (LSB is first index) in the STM32, which mean I had to reverse the bytes. For my condition, it was previously only "if tmp[24:27} == 111 and tmp[27:29] != 00", which I changed to be sure that I don't miss a case, but unfortunelately, it gave me the same answer. For the detour, I needed to translate hex to binary, then put them all one after another, so I could do the above code.

Comment: @Hugo  You wrote: "I do invert the bits ... because they're written in little endian (LSB is first index). Big or little Endian concern the byte ordering. They have nothing to do with bit ordering. And I used term 'detour' because it is easier to work with bytes. For example, a 32 bits instruction start with 0xEy where y is 1..F and can be coded with (( tmp[0] & 0xE) == 0xE) and (tmp[0] & 0x18 != 0). No need to shuffle bits.

Comment: This post is now very messy and we still do not know where is the problem. Would it be possible to start a new post and delete this one. And please, show content of input file (a few lines), what is provided to 'generate_instruction_file' and your output file (a few lines)., Then tell us what you think is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour Hugo!
You said your input file is a hex file.
In a hex file, each Ascii character represent 4 bits.
So, a 32 bits instruction requires 8 characters but you read 32.
Two possibilities:

- your input is not a hex file, or
- you confuse bits and bytes

Can you show us the first 64 characters of your input file?

Comment: Yes, here are the first 4 lines of my hexadecimal code :

S3250800000068040020A9010008350F0008250E0008310F0008B5020008CD130008000000001E
S32508000020000000000000000000000000390F0008B902000800000000370F00083B0F0008FF
S32508000040C3010008C3010008C3010008C3010008C3010008C3010008C3010008C301000832
S32508000060C3010008C3010008C3010008C3010008C3010008C3010008C3010008C301000812
They're in a .srec file, so the first 12 bits and the last two are not useful

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SREC_(file_format) these four lines are all 32-bit addresses with 0x25 byte count. Do you have examples of the 16-bit you are also trying to identify?

Comment: @ukBaz Don't confuse 32 bits addresses with 32 bits instructions.

Comment: So am I looking in the data part of the S-Record for a 32-bit or 16-bit word boundary that starts with `E` to find 16-bit commands. Is that correct? In which case there are no 16 bit commands in this example?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the second possibility is the right one.
You will need more rigor in your terminology.
For example, you wrote in comment: 'the first 12 bits ...'.
But in fact, it is 12 characters. It seem you mix up bits and characters.
You will need to do some reading about 'bits', 'bytes' and 'hexadecimal' to refresh your fundamentals.

As I mentioned in my first answer, a hex file contains ascii characters and each one represent 4 bits of binary data. So, a 32 bits machine instruction will require 8 characters (not 32 as you think).  A srec file is a hex file with some metadata ('S',type, length, load_address, data and checksum).
srec file format is documented in https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-Record
A good srec decoder must take care of all these elements.
You will have to redesign your program to include this:

- read a line
- determine length of load_address field from record type (character 1)
- compute position of data field (12 for records of type 3)
- get length of data from characters 2 and 3. Multiply by 2 and subtract length of metadata
- extract data
- decode instructions and isolate 16 bits instructions
- generate output
- continue with other input lines

When your new program will be ready, edit your post and resubmit. We will continue together.
"Le succès naît de la persévérance." (proverbe turc).

Comment: Yeah, sorry for my mistakes, I was tired when I posted. All of this is already done (in others functions), I just have posted the function that is reading a 8192 bits line (created by reading the 64 hexadecimal characters of every line and converting them in binary) (in my case), by group of 16, and that tranforms it in big endian notation, then write the corresponding 16 or 32 bits (according to the rule I explained) in a file. All I need is to understand why some instructions are not interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I took the "wrong output" from your question and recreated what I thought was the input data.

I then modified your function to print out what comparisons it was doing.

Your result was:

1. 32-bit
2. 32-bit
3. 16-bit
4. 32-bit

Using my data I got the same.

This is the code I used:

```py
def generate_instructions_file():
    # Example of wrong output given in question
    x_data = ("11110000000000001101001111111011"
              "11110000000000001111100001000101"
              "1111100000011110"
              "11110000010011110100100000011100")
    # reversed engineered input data
    data = ("1111101111010011"
            "0000000011110000"
            "0100010111111000"
            "0000000011110000"
            "0001111011111000"
            "0001110001001000"
            "0100111111110000")
    i = 0
    while i < len(data)-15:
        tmp = data[i:i+32]
        print(f"\nLooking at: {tmp} [{int(tmp, 2).to_bytes(4, 'little').hex()}]")
        print(f"\t'{tmp[24:27]}' == '111' and ('{tmp[27:29]}' != '00' or '{tmp[27:29]}' == '01' or '{tmp[27:29]}' == '10' or '{tmp[27:29]}' == '11')")
        print(f"\t{tmp[24:27] == '111'} and ({tmp[27:29] != '00'} or {tmp[27:29] == '01'} or {tmp[27:29] == '10'} or {tmp[27:29] == '11'})")
        if tmp[24:27] == '111' and (tmp[27:29] != '00' or tmp[27:29] == '01' or tmp[27:29] == '10' or tmp[27:29] == '11'):
            print("\t32-bit instruction")
            i += 32
        else:
            print("\t16-bit instruction")
            i += 16

if __name__ == '__main__':
    generate_instructions_file()
```

Which gave the following transcript:

```
Looking at: 11111011110100110000000011110000 [f000d3fb]
    '111' == '111' and ('10' != '00' or '10' == '01' or '10' == '10' or '10' == '11')
    True and (True or False or True or False)
    32-bit instruction

Looking at: 01000101111110000000000011110000 [f000f845]
    '111' == '111' and ('10' != '00' or '10' == '01' or '10' == '10' or '10' == '11')
    True and (True or False or True or False)
    32-bit instruction

Looking at: 00011110111110000001110001001000 [481cf81e]
    '010' == '111' and ('01' != '00' or '01' == '01' or '01' == '10' or '01' == '11')
    False and (True or True or False or False)
    16-bit instruction

Looking at: 00011100010010000100111111110000 [f04f481c]
    '111' == '111' and ('10' != '00' or '10' == '01' or '10' == '10' or '10' == '11')
    True and (True or False or True or False)
    32-bit instruction
```

The third value checked for is `01010` which gets classified as 16-bit but isn't `11100` that you specified as how 16-bit instructions are identified.

What should `01010` be classified as?

Comment: An instruction is 32-bits if it starts with '111' but they must not be followed by '00' (therefore an instruction starting with '11100' is a 16-bits). 01010 should then be a 16-bit instruction. To be even more precise, an instruction is 16-bit if it doesn't start with '111' or start with '11100', else it's a 32-bit.

Comment: So you code is doing the right thing?

Comment: Not entirely, because on my first message, I show that the third line is written as a 16-bit instruction, however it should be a 32-bit one (because it starts with 11111), and so taking the first 16 bits of the fourth line as the rest of the line, meaning the fourth line should be a 16-bits (it would start with 01001)

Comment: I took your code from your first message in the function `generate_instructions_file`. You appear to be checking bits 24:29 which are `01010` on the third check which is why it gets output as a 16-bit line. Please don't link to locations off of stackoverflow. Please update your question with a minimal runnable example with input data and expected output. A few lines of srec file should be all that is necessary if you identify which should be 16-bit and which should be 32-bit