# Sorting 16 and 32 bits instructions of STM in Python using endianness

Tags: python, binary, stm32, endianness

*[Update of my old post]*

I am using Python to read a hex file containing a STM32 code, translated to a one-line binary, and then re-written in a file with only one instruction per line.

That last part is the problem, because my code is not working properly : some 32-bits instructions are interpreted as a 16-bits instruction, causing the code to not properly divide the instructions.

Here is the code i use :

```
import json


def function(filepath):
    STMfile = open(filepath)  # Read the file containing the data
    STMfileLines = STMfile.readlines()
    data_STMfile = ""
    for STMfileLine in STMfileLines:
        data_STMfile += STMfileLine[12:-3]  # Taking only the data of each line
    data_binary = ""
    for c in data_STMfile:
        data_binary += str(bin(int(c, 16))[2:].zfill(4))  # Converting each hex character in binary of 4 bits
    instruction_file = open("./instructions_file.txt", "w")
    i = 0
    while i < len(data_binary)-15:
        tmp = data_binary[i:i+32]
        if tmp[24:27] == '111' and tmp[27:29] != '00':  # 32-bits condition
            instruction_file.write(tmp[24:] + tmp[16:24] + tmp[8:16] + tmp[:8] + '\n')
            i += 32
        else:
            tmp = data_binary[i:i+16]
            instruction_file.write(tmp[8:] + tmp[:8] + '\n')
            i += 16


if __name__ == '__main__':
    function("./clignoter_led.srec")
```

The file 'clignoter_led.srec' is :

```
S3250800000000400120650100081D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200080000000040
S325080000200000000000000000000000001D0200081D020008000000001D0200081D02000816
S325080000401D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200085A
S325080000601D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200083A
S325080000801D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081A
S325080000a01D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D020008FA
S325080000c01D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D020008DA
S325080000e01D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D020008BA
S325080001001D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D0200081D02000899
S325080001201D02000810B5054C237833B9044B13B10448AFF300800123237010BD04000020C4
S32508000140000000006802000808B5034B1BB103490348AFF3008008BD0000000008000020A2
S325080001606802000823488546AFF3008022482349234A002302E0D458C4500433C4188C423E
S32508000180F9D3204A204C002301E013600432A242FBD300F045F800F01EF81C484FF0010178
S325080001a00268114301601A484FF48061026811430160704717484FF02001026811430160D8
S325080001c0704714486FF0200102681140016070470138FDD17047FFF7E0FFFFF7EBFF0E48E2
S325080001e00068FFF7F5FFFFF7ECFF0B480068FFF7EFFFF2E7004001200000002004000020A1
S325080002008802000804000020200000201C380240000002401400024000000020FEE70000A7
S3250800022070B500260C4D0D4C641BA410A64209D100F01AF800260A4D0A4C641BA410A642CE
S3250800024005D170BD55F8043B98470136EEE755F8043B98470136F2E7800200088002000887
S325080002608002000884020008F8B500BFF8BC08BC9E467047F8B500BFF8BC08BC9E4670475A
S3250800028049010008250100083C55050000000000000000000000000000000000000000003A
S325080002a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000030
S325080002c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010
S325080002e00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000F0
S325080003002846A4EB0E0440EA03409EE7C1F120078B4022FA07FC4CEA030C25FA07FA4FEA6D
S325080003201C49BAFBF9F820FA07F309FB18AA8D401FFA8CFE1D4300FA01F308FB0EF02C0CD3
S3250800034044EA0A44A04202FA01F20BD91CEB040408F1FF3A80F08880A04240F28580A8F1F3
S3250800036002086444241AB4FBF9F009FB104400FB0EFEADB245EA0444A64508D91CEB0404D7
S3250800038000F1FF356CD2A6456AD90238644440EA0840A0FB0295A4EB0E04AC42C846AE46A7
S325080003a056D353D0002E69D0B3EB080264EB0E0422FA01F304FA07F71F43CC40C6E90074D6
S325080003c0002147E70CFA02FCC2F1200125FA01F34FEA1C4720FA01F195400D43B3FBF7F172
S325080003e007FB11331FFA8CFE280C40EA034001FB0EF3834204FA02F408D91CEB000001F1D5
S70500000000FA
```

As explained in my old post, an instruction is 32-bits if it starts with '111' but they must not be followed by '00' (therefore an instruction starting with '11100' is a 16-bits, and the instructions starting by '11101', '11110', '11111' are 32-bits instructions, all other starts are 16-bits ones).

When I run this function with the above file, the resulting file (instructions_file.txt) contains these lines :

```
(198) 11110000000000001101001111111011
(199) 11110000000000001111100001000101
(200) 1111100000011110
(201) 11110000010011110100100000011100
```

Here, the third line is supposed to be a 32-bits instruction, and so the 4th should be 16-bits, yet my code didn't recognize the third line as a 16-bits instruction.

I've verified every index, they are correct.

I've tried different hex file (they are directly downloaded from STM32CubeProgrammer), they all have this problem.

Comment: None of the four lines start with "11100".

Comment: @pmacfarlane Yes, but the third line starts with '11111', which is supposed to be a 32 bit instruction. Therefore, my code should indicate the 3rd line as a 32-bits and the fourth line as the last 16 bits of that line

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Where do the ranges [24:27] and [27:29] come from if you are testing the first 5 bits of a 32-bit number?

Comment: Can I suggest that we restrict the test to just one line from the srec file. I would propose `S325080001e00068FFF7F5FFFFF7ECFF0B480068FFF7EFFFF2E7004001200000002004000020A1`. This looks like it has some that start `11110` (32-bit) and `11100` (16-bit). I extracted the data bytes with `data = "S325080001e00068FFF7F5FFFFF7ECFF0B480068FFF7EFFFF2E7004001200000002004000020A1"` and `bytes.fromhex(data[12:-2])`. You have `-3` in your code which I think is wrong although it makes no difference in your code. From that srec line could you tell us what the commands are you expect to be found?

Comment: @pmacfarlane In the STM32, the code is written in litte endian, so I have to check the first 5 bits of the last byte to check.

Comment: @ukBaz You just made me point a coding error by making me do my code by hand. When I was trying the line 'S325080001e00068FFF7F5FFFFF7ECFF0B480068FFF7EFFFF2E7004001200000002004000020A1', I found the first 2 instructions as expected, but for the next 32-bits sequence, I check the bits 24-29 and found that's it's a 16-bits (00001 are the bits 24-29), and the start of the 32 bits sequence is '1111011001111111' which would be a 32-bits instruction ! But it is treated as a 16 bits one, therefore it make this problem I can't solve, and I will need my teacher to explain it to me! Thank you very much!

Comment: When you say "an instruction is 32-bits if it starts with '111' ", what do you mean? Is the starting point at the most significant bit of the most significant byte? Or is it the least significant bit of the least significant byte? Do you have a link to a STM manual?

Comment: If you do a `print(tmp)` for debugging after `tmp = data_binary[i:i+32]`, you will find the bug, basically your code within the `else:` took the wrong part of the data.